# Parsing machine-generated SQL in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ninjas,

this is a little bit hard.

I have an application's audit database based on SQL Server 2012. Inside there is a table with NTEXT column that contains raw text of sql queries. The queries are machine-like generated and they're not 'human friendly' readable (column is up to 20000 chars long, has a lot of aliases etc).

**I am looking for a tool that allows me to parse that sql queries texts and will list all the columns and tables that are used in the query.**

Up to now we've tried to figure out the algorithm on our own. But maybe there is a ready tool that will do it automaticly.

Thanks in advance for your help

Kaspar_

Comment: I think that's the job for a parser library.  I've done something similar for Teradata SQL.  What programming language would you prefer to use, if some programming is required? (as it should be,  since you are on Stack Overflow :-)

Comment: Have you tried using SMO?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sqlparser.parser.aspx

Comment: Could be Powershell, C# or Python. That stored queries are Oracle based

Comment: Are you looking for a C# snippet that does this?

Comment: C# snippet or an example of a library usage would be fine.

Comment: My snippet below doesn't figure all of the ins and outs for you, but I hope to get you started.  If it were me, I would use EntityFramework to create a DbSet on the table that you are mentioning here, then use Linq to run through all of the rows in your table passing the statements to the Parser.  You will get be the symbols and you should be able to index into the column collections and the tables.

Comment: Do you need it adjusted for Sql 2012?

Comment: With Java/JDBC you could just prepare (but not execute) the query, then use `PreparedStatement.getMetaData()` to get information about the columns

Answer (score 0):

Create a new C# project.  NuGet package id="Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom" version="13.0.1601.5" targetFramework="net46"

Then you can do all kinds of cool things.  Here is some sample code to capture parse errors.  You will want to use the Parser that corresponds to your version of SQL Server naturally.

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;



namespace <EnterNamespaceHere>
{
    public class ParsingError
    {
        public ParsingError(ParseError error)
        {
            Number = error.Number;
            Offset = error.Offset;
            Line = error.Line;
            Column = error.Column;
            Message = error.Message;
        }
        public int Column { get; private set; }
        public int Line { get; private set; }
        public string Message { get; private set; }
        public int Number { get; private set; }
        public int Offset { get; private set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Error {Number} at offset {Offset} ({Line},{Column}): '{Message}'";
        }

    }

    public static class TSqlHelper
    {
        public static bool ParseSyntax(string sql,
          out IEnumerable<ParsingError> reportedErrors)
        {
            TSqlParser parser = new TSql130Parser(true);
            IList<ParseError> errors;
            using (StringReader rdr = new StringReader(sql))
            {
                parser.Parse(rdr, out errors);
            }
            if (errors != null && errors.Count > 0)
            {
                reportedErrors = errors.Select(
                  pe => new ParsingError(pe));
            return false;
        }
        reportedErrors = null;
        return true;
    }
  }
}
```